# Error in task sunspot:mongo:reindex in Sunspot Solr with Mongoid

Tags: solr, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have solr with sunspot_mongo gem. When I try run sunspot:mongo:reindex I get this error:

```
reindexing House
rake aborted!
RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error
Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: no segments* file found in org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/home/ubuntu/Desktop/PROJECT/solr/data/development/index: files:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: no segments* file found in org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/home/ubuntu/Desktop/PROJECT/solr/data/development/index: files:
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1068)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:418)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processCommit(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:169)
at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:69)
at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:54)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1316)

Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><commit/>"
```

I have stopped and start solr with rake sunspot:solr:stop and I get:

```
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.10) (6b20-1.9.10-0ubuntu1~10.10.2)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
Successfully stopped Solr ...
```

I have started Solr with command rake sunspot:solr:start and I get:

```
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.10) (6b20-1.9.10-0ubuntu1~10.10.2)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
Successfully started Solr ...
```

---

**EDITED**

thank you but not working. I have delete index folder and I have rerun **sunspot:solr:start** and when I try create a new register or run **sunspot:solr:start**

```
reindexing House
rake aborted!
RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error
Error: no segments* file found in org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/home/ubuntu/Desktop/PROJECT/solr/data/development/index: files: lucene-c43d1f7f8a62a2ff6fed0bddcce1a574-write.lock

java.io.FileNotFoundException: no segments* file found in  org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/home/ubuntu/Desktop/PROJECT/solr/data/development/index: files: lucene-c43d1f7f8a62a2ff6fed0bddcce1a574-write.lock
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:655)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:538)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:306)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.init(IndexWriter.java:1577)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1402)
at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:190)
at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.createMainIndexWriter(UpdateHandler.java:98)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.openWriter(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:173)

Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><add><doc><field name=\"id\">House 4ed7c2f31d41c8327e000006</field><field name=\"type\">House</field><field name=\"class_name\">House</field><field name=\"content_text\">This is a new house</field></doc></add>"
```

Always appear this:

**c43d1f7f8a62a2ff6fed0bddcce1a574-write.lock**

However when I commented this in my model:

```
  #searchable do
    #text :content
  #end
```

The rake task working fine and not show error but not index the model.

Any idea??

Comment: Solr looks for the segments file in the index folder, if it exists. Delete the index folder, and the Solr start should recreate the index folder with the segments files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your index is corrupted. Stop Solr, delete the `solr/data/development/index` folder, and re-run `sunspot:solr:start` to recreate it.

Comment: nice one! we had a power outage and it seemed to have corrupted the index, struggled with this one for 3 hours.

Answer (score 5):

@hyperrjas

Besides deleting the index folder mentioned by Nick, you need to kill the already-start solr process, by run `ps aux | grep 'solr'` to find. It should work now.

Comment: have been banning my head at this for some time! tx!